# Reading stdout from external application over pipe without blocking

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I'm trying to read stdout without waiting for end of process. I tried [this](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html) but this didn't work for me. Here is my actual code of function

```
void startShowingStdout(FILE* pipe)
{
   char buffer = 0;
   struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
   tcgetattr(fileno(pipe),&old_tio);
   new_tio=old_tio;
   new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHO);
   tcsetattr(fileno(pipe),TCSANOW,&new_tio);

   while((buffer = getc(pipe)) != EOF) std::cout << buffer << std::flush;
   tcsetattr(fileno(pipe),TCSANOW,&old_tio);
}
```

In this version stdout appears after program end. Is any possibility to capture stdout before exit?

Comment: Change `buffer` to type `int` or you won't never see EOF.

Comment: under linux and gcc, the code from the referred page worked correctly for me.

Comment: @user3629249 Yes but code from reffered page uses keybaord as input. I want use pipe in my case to capture stdout from other application and immidietly show it. Actually messages from other program are store in buffer until progrm end. Then pipe sends EOF.